# Expectation of Itô stochastic integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

$$E\left[\int_0^\infty \left|\int_0^t(W(s))^2 \, dW(s)\right|^{\,2} e^{-t} \, dt\right]$$

Not sure if, by Itô Isometry, it is possible to pull the expectation operation inside in the integral because of the $$e^{-t}$$ term.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_t = \int_0^t W_s^2 dW_s$. You want to compute $C = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty X_t^2 e^{-t} dt]$. Since $X_t^2 e^{-t} \geq 0$, by Fubini's Theorem we have
\begin{align*}
C =& \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}[X_t^2 e^{-t}] dt \\
=& \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t W_s^4 ds\right] dt \\
=& \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_s^4] ds dt \\
=& \int_0^\infty \int_0^t 3e^{-t}s^3 ds dt \\
=& \int_0^\infty t^3 e^{-t} dt 
\end{align*}
where the second equality follows from the Ito Isometry and the third by another application of Fubini.